# Tweaking const map key

Tags: c++

I want to use STL map with keys which are logically constant (and my code using map ensures never violating key ordering) but actually implemented as variable. For instance,

```cpp
struct K { int ka, kb; };

struct my_less : std::less<K> {
    bool operator()(const K& l, const K& r) const
        { return l.ka+l.kb < r.ka+r.kb; }
};

std::map<K, int, my_less> m;

// put something into m and now modify keys

K& k = *const_cast<K *>(&m.begin()->first);
k.ka++;
k.kb--;  // I skip code for verifying logical key immutability for the sake of example simplification
```

It works (map ordering is not broken) but it looks ugly. Are there any better alternatives?

Extra indirection with pointer (pointer made const without making data const) is possible but it incurs overhead (and adds unnecessary complexity).

Moving variable key part from key into value is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boost::multi_index is a reasonable alternative for this case. It supports changes preserving order without much overhead.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good reason why you can't neatly edit the keys of a map - you're really not supposed to do it!  In your case it may appear to not break the map ordering, but this is not guaranteed!    (Think what would happen if you modify two keys to have the same ka and kb values?)

The correct way to do this would be to erase the element from the map, and re-insert it with a new key.

```
std::map<K, int, my_less> m;

// Push our starting object into the map
K key;
key.ka = 42;
key.kb = 123;

m[key] = 1234;

// Get the first element
auto iter = m.begin();

// make a new key
K key2;
key2 = iter->first;
key2.ka++;
key2.kb--;

int value = iter->second;

// remove old value
m.erase(iter);

// insert new value
m[key2] = value;
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way, but it adds substantial overhead, unacceptable in my case.

Comment: By substantial overhead, do you mean your value is a complex object, which is stored by value in the map, so gets copied on insertion?  Switching to a smart pointer value would mitigate that, since you'd only be removing and reinserting the pointer, and not having to reduplicate your value object.

Comment: No, the tree insertion/removal itself is not that cheap. I've added clarification to the original question: constant key order is guaranteed by user code.

Comment: So your code is modifying they keys in a large map many times?  It really sounds like you should rethink how this data is stored/indexed.  (You need to decide if you want *fast* code or *safe* code, or ideally *both*)

Comment: Using invariants in user code doesn't mean unsafe code. I just add my library layer which verifies this invariant.